# What is "one-loop cosmological constant"?

Tags: string-theory, terminology, quantum-gravity, cosmological-constant

I'm following [Witten's essay](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/PT.3.2980) and I'm trying to understand the UV divergence.
When he writes:

> In quantum field theory, this Feynman diagram with a single proper-time parameter τ, underlies the one-loop cosmological constant.

1. Is this loop the same loop from Loop Quantum Gravity (LQG)?
2. If the answer for the first question is yes, is the "one-loop cosmological constant" just the contribution of one-loop in this theory for the cosmological constant?

Comment: You can't learn physics from essays. Anyway the answers are 1: No, 2: Non-applicable

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-loop_Feynman_diagram e.g. figure 1 in the essay

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with Loop Quantum Gravity (I removed the corresponding tag)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a long comment made with the intention to help you to discover the answer by yourself.

Our **goal** is to compute the one-loop partition function for the closed string vacuum. That's relevant because the cosmological constant is an energy density, then is natural to compute the (one-loop) partition function of the vacuum in order to define the expected (one-loop) correction to the *free-energy* of the vacuum.

**Observation (1):**  There is only one relevant Feynman diagram arising from the closed string sector that is relevant for this problem, that's because, by definition of *"vacuum"*, we are assuming that no other perturbative nor non-perturbative states (open strings, branes etc.) are present. The relevant Feynman diagram is the torus partition function with no punctures; the torus partition function arises as the one-loop (genus-one) closed string partition function and the absence of punctures is the statement of the absence of asymptotic closed string states on a closed string vacuum. All this is done in detail in the book *Introduction to Conformal Field theory: With Applications to String Theory* (chapter 4).

**Observation (2):** The torus partition function depends on a particular moduli $\tau$, $Z_{torus}=Z_{torus}(\tau)$. That's bad because we want to preserve modular invariance (why?), but $Z_{torus}$ is not modular invariant, however. The key is now to write the simplest modular invariant that can be written in terms of $Z_{torus}(\tau)$. Convince yourself that the answer is:  $$\int_{Torus} \frac{d \tau d \bar{\tau}}{im(\tau)} Z_{torus}(\tau, \bar{\tau}),$$ if you have any doubts or want a first principle derivation, consult the discussion around equation 4.1 in the book *Introduction to Conformal Field theory: With Applications to String Theory* (chapter 4).

**Observation (3):** Then, the one-loop cosmological constant in string theory is given as $$\Lambda \sim \int_{Torus} \frac{d \tau d \bar{\tau}}{im(\tau)} Z_{torus}(\tau, \bar{\tau}).$$